# Counting the number of characters in a row of a cell array, including spaces?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, character, cell

I have a cell array that has strings in each row. I want to count the number of characters in each row of the cell array, including spaces. How do I do this in matlab?

Thanks for your answer, I'm a bit stuck though in my code

```
fid = fopen('thenames.txt', 'w');
if fid ~= -1
    disp (' The file opened sucessfully')
else 
    disp (' The file did not open sucessfully')
end
string1 = input('Enter a name:','s');
countstr =1;
fprintf(fid, 'Name %d is %s\n', countstr, string1)
TF = strcmp ('stop', string1);
while TF == 0;
    countstr = countstr+1;
    string1 = input ('Enter a name:','s');
    TF = strcmp ('stop', string1);
    if TF ==0
fprintf(fid, 'Name %d is %s\n', countstr, string1)
    elseif TF == 1
            disp ('Ok. No more names')
    end

end
totalnames = countstr - 1;
fprintf(fid, 'There were %d total names given\n', totalnames)

fid = fopen('thenames.txt');
if fid ~= -1
disp (' The file opened sucessfully')
else 
disp (' The file did not open sucessfully')
end
cellarray2 = [];
cellarray2 = textscan (fid ,'%s %d %s %s');
newcellarray = {cellarray2{4}}
charsPerRow = sum(cellfun(@numel,newcellarray),2)
```

I am ultimately trying to end up with a cell array that will store the name as a string in the first column  and the second column will store the number of characters within the string as an integer. That would be the last bit of my code starting from cellarray2

Comment: Can you just spit out the contents of `newcellarray`?

Comment: You should do `newcellarray = cellarray2{4}` instead of `newcellarray = {cellarray2{4}}` otherwise it is a cell array inside a cell array.  then you can use `cellfun` as shown. Then follow my updated answer to add on the column with character counts.

Comment: No problem. If my comments and answer were helpful, I'd appreciate if you would accept and even upvote if you feel inclined.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Say you have a cell array `C`:

```
>> C = {'a','b2','c';'x','y','z';'aa','bb','cc'}
C = 
    'a'     'b2'    'c' 
    'x'     'y'     'z' 
    'aa'    'bb'    'cc'
```

Then use `cellfun` and `sum`:

```
>> charsPerRow = sum(cellfun(@numel,C),2)
charsPerRow =
     4
     3
     6
```

Say you want to tag this on to the cell:

```
>> C2 = [C num2cell(charsPerRow)]
C2 = 
    'a'     'b2'    'c'     [4]
    'x'     'y'     'z'     [3]
    'aa'    'bb'    'cc'    [6];
```